# Converse to Bauer's maximum principle

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, geometric-functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff real locally convex topological vector space and $K$ be a nonempty compact subset. Bauer's maximum principle states that a convex upper semicontinuous function $f\colon K \to \mathbb R$ attains its maximum on $K$ at an extreme point of $K$.

My question is the converse: given an extreme point $x$ of $K$, does there always exist a convex upper semicontinuous function $f\colon K\to\mathbb R$ such that $f(x) > f(y)$ for all $y\in K \setminus \{x\}$?

I have found that if $K$ has nonempty interior, the Hahn-Banach convex separation theorem concludes there is indeed such a function (which is even a continuous linear form on $X$). At the same time, this is a restrictive hypothesis.

Comment: Any constant function $f:K\to\mathbb R$ satisfies the conditions of Bauer's theorem and attains its maximum at an extreme point of $K\,.$ In what sense are you looking for a converse? What is "uniquely maximal at $x$"?

Comment: In the sense that it has a unique maximum on $K$, which happens to be $x$, in particular a constant function will not do. I have edited the wording so to be more explicit. The question is essentially whether or not extreme points are really characterized as optimal solutions. In other words, is Bauer maximum principle the strongest it can be, or is there an even smaller set we can restrict our attention to?

Comment: Well, one can take $f\colon K \to \mathbb R$ equal to $0$ on $K\setminus\{x\}$ and $1$ at $x$. But I still wonder whether there exists a continuous linear form that separates $x$ from $K$, or at least a continuous convex function uniquely maximal at $x$.

Comment: Could the following work: let $C$ be the closed convex hull of $K$, which is again compact. If $C$ has nonempty interior then by Hahn-Banach theorem there is a supporting hyperplane of $C$ at the given extreme point of $K$. This is the desired $f$.

Comment: $K$ is compact convex, so the closure of its convex hull is $K$ itself. As I mention in the third paragraph, if it has nonempty interior, indeed extreme points can be separated by continuous linear forms. But what about when $K$ has empty interior?